# Spring microservice jwt authentication

Tags: spring, jwt, microservices, netflix-zuul, okta

I have been trying to build a spring distributed application that works on JWT.
Github repo -  https://github.com/dhananjay12/spring-microservice-demo

**Service Description**

- product-service : A simple downstream service having protected routes
- jwt-resoure-server : A jar that when included in downstream services make it a rsourceserver that extract jwt token and set it in security contex.
- eureka-service : Discovery service
- zuul-server : Edge server

Now product-service with jwt-resoure-server , works fine:
[image]

Setting up zuul and eureka:

[image]

But if I hit from the zuul server I get the following error:

[image]

I am using okta for authentication. I am not sure, where the error is coming from. Is it zuul not passing the token or some place else.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick look.  It looks like your gateway is NOT a ResourceServer, so it wouldn't accept an access token.

Also note, you shouldn't put secrets like (including access tokens) on GitHub or StackOverflow. I'd recommend you replace the secrets associated with this post.

Comment: Adding @EnableResourceServer in zuul server did it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Although I do have to provide the public key which I have to built it via code from a json object provided by okta  and then paste it in application.yml. Can you suggest an easier way.

Comment: For Okta's Spring Integration: https://github.com/okta/samples-java-spring/tree/master/resource-server  It will handle the key for you.

Comment: Ran into another issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646207/spring-zuul-for-authorization-code-grant-type
Any suggestions?